# Finding all word pairs from range of strings in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Let's say I have a column of values, each of which is a string.

| A |
| --- |
| This is a string |
| This is longer than that |
| My favorite is short |
| But sometimes short is longer |
| How is a short longer |

I would like to extract all of the unique two-word combinations and count the number of times they occur without regard to capitalization.

For example, the data above would return:

| Pair | Count |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This is | 2 |  |
| is a | 2 |  |
| a string | 1 |  |
| is longer | 2 |  |
| longer than | 1 |  |
| than that | 1 |  |
| My favorite | 1 |  |
| favorite is | 1 |  |
| is short | 1 |  |
| But sometimes | 1 |  |
| sometimes short | 1 |  |
| short is | 1 |  |
| How is | 1 |  |
| a short | 1 |  |
| short longer | 1 |  |

I've tried split/join combinations, but I can't figure out how to sequence the discovery of each pair.

Answer (score 0):

See [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ouBPW9y3HJ_VQmTKUtkGeW1C_fI_HXthZZHm0hlR2_o/edit#gid=0).

Unique pairs of 2 word from column A are in column D as a result of following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 UNIQUE(
  FILTER(
  {"#";TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A2:A&" ")," "))}&" "&{TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A2:A&" ")," "));"#"},
  NOT(REGEXMATCH({"#";TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A2:A&" ")," "))}&" "&{TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A2:A&" ")," "));"#"},".*#")))))
```

Idea is make column of single words and concatenate is with the same column offset by 1 row.

Following part returns column of single words.

```
TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A2:A&" ")," "))
```

Then we shift it down, *please note that I used "#" symbol for shifting purposes and further filter and if original text contains "#" it won't be included in final result, so you can change that symbol if you need.*

```
{"#";TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A2:A&" ")," "))}
```

concatenate with other column and filter rows that would contain only one word.

Answer (score 0):

###### Using QUERY

`Order By` can be added to the QUERY

```
=QUERY(
  TOCOL(BYROW(A2:A6, LAMBDA(r, 
    TOROW(LET(txt,SPLIT(LOWER(r)," "),
    MAP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(txt)-1), LAMBDA(s,
      JOIN(" ",CHOOSECOLS(txt,s,s+1)))))))),1),
  "Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) Group by Col1 Label COUNT(Col1) ''")
```

<sub>**QUERY Version**</sub>
[image]

###### Using MAP

The formula can be wrapped in SORT

```
=LET(
  pairs,TOCOL(BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r, 
    TOROW(LET(txt,SPLIT(LOWER(r)," "),
    MAP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(txt)-1), LAMBDA(s,
      IFERROR(JOIN(" ",CHOOSECOLS(txt,s,s+1))))))))),1),
  MAP(UNIQUE(pairs), LAMBDA(u, {u, COUNTIF(pairs,u)})))
```

<sub>**MAP Version**</sub>
[image]